# how can i resize image(logo) when scroll down the web page

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

how could the reverse this function, i want to image(site logo) element resize(smaller) when scroll down the web page and back when scroll to top of page

http://jsfiddle.net/TwLuE/

I tried this:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  var s = Math.min(400, $(document).scrollTop()) + 100;
  $("img").width(s).height(s);
});​
```

but it works vice versa. apologize me for weak writing question in english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a prefix size in front:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var s = 400 - Math.min(400, $(document).scrollTop());
    $("img").width(s).height(s);
});
```

Tweak that `400` to your needs. `:)`

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pur9ruut/**